# CSS - making two elements overlap on small screen and taking each their own width on big screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have two div elements, one with some text and a button, and the other with an image, separate in a row, where the one with the text would take 4 columns and the other with image would take 8 columns. But on small screens the one with an image needs to take the full screen width, and the div  with text and a button needs to go over it as an overlay over image. Not sure what is the best way to achieve this, and how to do this with only css and media queries?
So this would be the html for big screens:

```
        <div class="header row">
          <div class="large-12 columns frontpage-header-content">
            <div class="snirky-snark-box">
              <h4>Vi arbeider med å bygge kompetanse, spre kunnskap og positiv energi i kreftsaken</h4>
              <button type="button" class="button">Støtt kreftsaken</button>
            </div>
            <div class="frontpage-header-image">
               <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/sfk-bg.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="header-title-bar">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="large-12 columns">
                <div class="title-bar">
                  <div class="title-bar-left">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/menu-icon.svg">
                    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-open="offCanvasLeft"></button>
                    <span class="title-bar-title">Meny</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="title-bar-right">
                    <span class="title-bar-title">Støtteforeningen for Kreftrammede</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.header -->
```

And what I am trying to achieve is this, small screen:

[image]

Big screen:

[image]

This is the css that I have so far:

```
.header {
  position: relative;
}

.header-title-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
}

.frontpage-header-image {
  width: 67%;
}

.frontpage-header-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.snirky-snark-box {
  width: 33%;
}

.promo {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

**Update:**

I have managed to achieve this like so:

```
@include breakpoint(medium down) {
  .frontpage-header-image {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
  }
  .snirky-snark-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }

  .header > .columns {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

But the image gets resized, I need it to have always the same height, I have tried to achieve that with setting the min-height but it didn't work:

```
.frontpage-header-image {
  width: 67%;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries to make the text-block on top of image by making it absolute like this and then align according to your needs.

```
@media (max-width: 750px){
  .snirky-snark-box { 
    width: 100%; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
```

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
}

.header-title-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
}

.frontpage-header-image {
  width: 67%;
}

.frontpage-header-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.snirky-snark-box {
  width: 33%;
}

.promo {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

@media (max-width: 750px){
  .snirky-snark-box { 
    width: 100%; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header row">
  <div class="large-12 columns frontpage-header-content">
    <div class="snirky-snark-box">
      <h4>Vi arbeider med å bygge kompetanse, spre kunnskap og positiv energi i kreftsaken</h4>
      <button type="button" class="button">Støtt kreftsaken</button>
    </div>
    <div class="frontpage-header-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x150">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="header-title-bar">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="title-bar">
          <div class="title-bar-left">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/menu-icon.svg">
            <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-open="offCanvasLeft"></button>
            <span class="title-bar-title">Meny</span>
          </div>
          <div class="title-bar-right">
            <span class="title-bar-title">Støtteforeningen for Kreftrammede</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it like this :

```
   <div>  <img src="logo.gif" style="width:400px;z-index: 899;float:left;position: absolute;margin: auto;margin-left: 0px;max-width: 100%;">
          <img src="logo.gif" style="width:400px;z-index:900;float:right;position: relative;margin-right: 0;margin-left: auto;display: inline-block;max-width: 100%;"></div>
```

you can ofcourse also make a css class for it